# Why does the order of binding buffers seem to matter in a simple WebGL program?

Tags: javascript, webgl

Sorry if this is really dumb. I'm having the weirdest WebGL issue. I've written a really basic WebGL program to render a sprite.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head><title></title>
<style>
html, body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden; }
canvas { position: absolute; top:0;left:0; cursor: none; }
</style></head><body>
<canvas id="webgltestingthing"></canvas>
<script>
var scene,gl,cursor,sh={};

var vertexShader="\
precision mediump float;\
attribute vec2 a_position;\
attribute vec2 a_texCoord;\
uniform vec2 u_resolution;\
varying vec2 v_texCoord;\
void main() {\
    gl_Position = vec4(a_position/u_resolution*2.0-1.0, 0, 1);\
    v_texCoord = a_texCoord;\
}";
var fragShader="\
precision mediump float;\
uniform sampler2D u_image;\
varying vec2 v_texCoord;\
void main() {\
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_image, v_texCoord);\
}";

function resizeScene() {
    document.getElementById("webgltestingthing").width = document.body.clientWidth;
    document.getElementById("webgltestingthing").height = document.body.clientHeight;
    if(gl) gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight); }
mouseX=-1000; mouseY=-1000;
function trackMouse(e) { e = e || window.event; mouseX=event.pageX; mouseY=event.pageY; }
function trackMouseOut() { mouseX=-1000; mouseY=-1000; }
function createShader(gl, type, source) {
    var shader = gl.createShader(type);
    gl.shaderSource(shader, source);
    gl.compileShader(shader);
    var success = gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS);
    if (success) { return shader; }
    console.log(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader)); gl.deleteShader(shader); }
function createProgram(gl, vertexShader, fragmentShader) {
    var program = gl.createProgram();
    gl.attachShader(program, vertexShader);
    gl.attachShader(program, fragmentShader);
    gl.linkProgram(program);
    var success = gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.LINK_STATUS);
    if (success) { return {p: program, a: {}, u: {}}; }
    console.log(gl.getProgramInfoLog(program)); gl.deleteProgram(program); }
function createTexture(url,onload) {
    this.img=new Image(); this.onload=onload; this.loaded=false;
    this.img.src=url;
    this.w=0; this.h=0; this.texture=gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, this.texture);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    postload=function() {
        gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, this.img);
        this.loaded=true; this.onload(); }
    this.img.addEventListener("load",postload.bind(this));
    return this; }
function renderSprite(t,x,y) {
    if(!t.loaded) return;
    var x1=x,y1=scene.clientHeight-y,x2=x+t.img.width,y2=y1-t.img.height;
    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, t.texture);
    gl.useProgram(sh.sprite.p);

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, sh.sprite.a.texCoordBuffer);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(sh.sprite.a.texCoord);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(sh.sprite.a.texCoord, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, sh.sprite.a.positionBuffer);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(sh.sprite.a.position);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([x1, y1, x2, y1, x1, y2, x1, y2, x2, y1, x2, y2]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(sh.sprite.a.position, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    gl.uniform2fv(sh.sprite.u.res, [scene.clientWidth, scene.clientHeight]);
    gl.uniform1i(sh.sprite.u.img, 0);

    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
}
function renderStuff() {
    gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    if(mouseX>0) renderSprite(cursor,mouseX,mouseY);
    requestAnimationFrame(renderStuff);
}
(function() {
    scene=document.getElementById("webgltestingthing"); resizeScene();
    window.addEventListener('resize', resizeScene, true);
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', trackMouse, true);
    scene.addEventListener('mouseout', trackMouseOut, true);
    gl=scene.getContext("experimental-webgl");

    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);
    sh.f_sprite = createShader(gl, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragShader);
    sh.v_bypixels = createShader(gl, gl.VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShader);

    sh.sprite = createProgram(gl, sh.v_bypixels, sh.f_sprite);
    sh.sprite.u.res = gl.getUniformLocation(sh.sprite.p, "u_resolution");
    sh.sprite.u.img = gl.getUniformLocation(sh.sprite.p, 'u_image');
    sh.sprite.a.position = gl.getUniformLocation(sh.sprite.p, "a_position");
    sh.sprite.a.positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    sh.sprite.a.texCoord = gl.getUniformLocation(sh.sprite.p, "a_texCoord");
    sh.sprite.a.texCoordBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, sh.sprite.a.texCoordBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    cursor=createTexture("graphics/cursor.png",function() { renderStuff(); });
})();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This displays a blank white screen. I'd hoped it would display the texture at the mouse position. There's no errors in the console or anything. Then I did some playing around and noticed something odd that I couldn't explain. I added this to my fragment shader:

```
if(v_texCoord==vec2(0.0,0.0)) gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
```

And indeed, it turns out the texture coordinate everywhere on the image is apparently 0.0/0.0! WebGL now correctly renders a red box in the position where the sprite is supposed to be, at the exact size of the sprite. So then my attention turned to the part where I set the buffer up to pass in the texture co-ordinate and something even weirder happened: if you swap around the code so that I set the position buffer first, like this (in the rendersprite function):

```
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, sh.sprite.a.positionBuffer);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(sh.sprite.a.position);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([x1, y1, x2, y1, x1, y2, x1, y2, x2, y1, x2, y2]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(sh.sprite.a.position, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, sh.sprite.a.texCoordBuffer);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(sh.sprite.a.texCoord);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(sh.sprite.a.texCoord, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
```

Now my red box isn't even there anymore! So that indicates to me that for some reason, whatever buffer I'm setting first on this simple shader is not working, but I can't see any reason why. I've tried all sorts of different ways and tried shuffling things around and such, no luck so far. I'm also confused about why the order matters at all.

Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your setup function you're using [`getUniformLocation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/getUniformLocation) to query the attribute locations, attributes however are not uniforms and their locations need to be queried using [`getAttribLocation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/getAttribLocation) instead.

Calling `getUniformLocation` on the attributes returns `null`  which is then casted to `0` in your `enableVertexAttribArray` and `vertexAttribPointer` calls, hence you're binding the vertex attributes to the same location.

```
sh.sprite.a.position = gl.getAttribLocation(sh.sprite.p, "a_position");
sh.sprite.a.positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
sh.sprite.a.texCoord = gl.getAttribLocation(sh.sprite.p, "a_texCoord");
sh.sprite.a.texCoordBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
```

Comment: I knew it would be something really stupid/obvious like that! Thanks, I'm marking it as the correct answer because that fixed the issue.